# Big-Oh of for loop with if-else statement

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, big-o

I'm wondering why is the tightest Big-Oh Complexity of the following code O(n^4) instead of O(n^5):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=1; i<n ; i++){ //O(n)
    for(int j=1; j<i*i; j++){ // O(n^2)
        if(j%i == 0)
            for(int k=0; k<j; k++) //O(n^2)
            sum++;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: The inner `sum++` operation gets executed sum(sum(i*j for j=1..(i-1)) for i=1..(n-1)) times. That's exactly 1/24 n (n + 1) (n + 2) (3 n + 1).

Answer (score 0):

- From math we know that a number `x` has at most `2*x^0.5` divisors.
- So if statement will be executed `j^0.5` times in worst case
- which equals to `n` since largest `j` is `n*n`

Answer (score 0):

It backs to the inner-most `if` condition. As `j%i == 0` is only true for `j = {i, 2*i, 3*i, ..., i * i}`, just `i` times the second loop will run in `O(i^2)`. Hence, the tight complexity is `O(n^4)`.